# How to give R's "matchit" a formula object via Python's r2py?

Tags: r, pandas, rpy2

I use `rpy2` to use R in Python. Especially I want to use the `MatchIt` package but stuck on a detail. The call to the primary function of that package *in R* looks like this

```
# R code
m.out1 <- matchit(
    gruppe ~ geschlecht + alter + pflege,
    data = df,
    method = "nearest",
    distance = "glm"
)
```

The first argument is a "formula". I don't have an idea how to create such an object/argument in Python code? The other three arguments are no problem. The error from rpy2 is this:

```
[WARNING] R[write to console]: Error: 'formula' must be a formula object.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface.py", line 813, in __call__
    raise embedded.RRuntimeError(_rinterface._geterrmessage())
rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError: Error: 'formula' must be a formula object.
```

This is the **Python** code producing that problem.

```
# Python code
import pandas
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.pandas2ri as pandas2ri

r_package_matchit = robjects.packages.importr('MatchIt')
func_matchit = robjects.r['matchit']

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'gruppe': list('IICC'),
    'geschlecht': list('mwmw'),
    'alter': range(4),
    'pflege': range(4)
})

# convert the data frame from Pandas to R
with robjects.conversion.localconverter(
    robjects.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    rdf = robjects.conversion.py2rpy(df)

func_matchit(formula='gruppe ~ geschlecht + alter + pflege',
             data=rdf, method='nearest',
             distance='glm')
```

Answer (score 0):

Mutch easier then I thougt. `rpy2` offers a [`Formula()`](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/robjects_formulae.html) for cases like this.

```
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects import Formula
# ...
func_matchit(formula=Formula('gruppe ~ geschlecht + alter + pflege'),
             data=rdf, method='nearest',
             distance='glm')
```